# Open File Dialog in Outlook (VBA) Error 438

Tags: vba, outlook, openfiledialog

I'm trying to open a File Dialog in Outlook via VBA. (Outlook 2010)

With the following code i get an Error:

> Runtime error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Private Sub btn_openPST_Click()
    Dim oFileDialog As FileDialog
    Set oFileDialog = myAppl.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With oFileDialog
        .Title = "Select your PST File"
        .ButtonName = "Ok"
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

myAppl is an Outlook.Application Object:

```
Dim myAppl As Outlook.Application
Set myAppl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think Outlook can open a file picker. I workaround is to open an Excel sheet and then open the file picker, then close the excel sheet. Try the following code, and be sure to import the **"Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library"** Reference into Outlook.

```
Private Sub openFDinOutlook()

    Dim xlObj As Excel.Application
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

    Set xlObj = New Excel.Application
    xlObj.Visible = False
    Set fd = xlObj.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fd
        .Title = "Select your PST File"
        .ButtonName = "Ok"
        .Show
    End With
    xlObj.Quit
    Set xlObj = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this. But does an Excel Windows pop up when i open an Excel Application?

Comment: It will, but you won't see it. It's not visible with the `xlObj.Visible = False` line. The excel file is closed when the script is through.

Comment: Thank you ver much Alex!