# Outlook VBA add hyperlink of chosen file in dialog

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to add the functionality in my Outlook (with VBA, I guess is easiest) to add a simple file dialog which takes the path of any files chosen and adds them to the email body as a hyperlink.

The idea of this is for network files to be shared amongst colleagues, instead of attaching them to the email, but just as easy to do.

This is my code so far, I can't even get the dialog to open, and I've had a good look at trying to get `COMDLG32.ocx`, so far I can't seem to make anything work.

```
Sub Main2()

Dim CDLG As Object
Set CDLG = CreateObject("MSComDlg.CommonDialog")
With CDLG
.DialogTitle = "Get me a File!"
.Filter = _
  "Documents|*.doc|Templates|*.dot|Text Files|*.txt"
.ShowOpen
MsgBox .FileName
End With
Set CDLG = Nothing

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance, hopefully someone can show me how this is done!

Just for those who need it; OS Windows 10, Office 2010 H&B (yes, I know it's out of date :))

Comment: I tested your code On Outlook 2010 and it works, the file dialog opens as expected and the msgbox display any chosen file's path. So give a bit more information about your issue

Comment: I get a Runtime error `-2147221005 (800401f3)`, unless you've got Visual Studio installed...? That might be why you can load the dialog...

Comment: Indeed I've got VS installed. I am on my way back from the office. I'll have a look to your issue tommorow if you haven't received a valid answer.

Comment: This is built into Outlook.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-or-edit-a-hyperlink-5d8c0804-f998-4143-86b1-1199735e07bf?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US and https://www.msoutlook.info/question/21

Comment: @niton yes, I realised that but I was looking to automate it with a file dialog.... if you see what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no direct way to open a `FileDialog` in `Outlook 2010 VBA`.

The following macro (inspired by a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33347187/1911064)) makes use of `Excel` to circumvent this:

```
Public Function promptFileName(title As String, filter As String) As String
    '  requires project reference to "Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library"
    Dim xlObj As Excel.Application
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
    Dim name As String
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim filterArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set xlObj = New Excel.Application
    xlObj.Visible = False
    Set fd = xlObj.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    name = ""
    With fd
        .title = title
        .ButtonName = "Ok"
        .Filters.Clear
        filterArray = Split(filter, "|")

        For i = LBound(filterArray) To UBound(filterArray) - 1 Step 2
            .Filters.Add filterArray(i), filterArray(i + 1), 1 + i \ 2
        Next i

        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each vItem In .SelectedItems
                name = vItem
                Exit For
            Next
        End If
    End With
    xlObj.Quit
    Set xlObj = Nothing
    promptFileName = name
End Function

Private Sub testPromptFile
    Dim name as String
    name = promptFileName("a test", "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*")
    MsgBox name
End Sub
```

`Outlook 2013` and beyond provide an `Office.FileDialog` class for this purpose.

Comment: thanks - that seems like a solution. However when I call it, it returns `Argument not optional`, I've added the reference, and tried to call it as a sub - haven't yet tried to add the hyperlink as I think that uses the Word editor... :(

Comment: Have a look at the test call in my answer. This should get you started.

Comment: works like a dream - now got to work on the hyperlink part...... thanks for your help, @Axel

Answer (score 0):

You can press a button with Outlook VBA.

```
Sub ExecuteMso_strId()

Dim objItem As Object
Dim strId As String

' Text appears when hovering over icon
'  when adding buttons to a Quick Access toolbar or a ribbon
strId = "HyperlinkInsert"

On Error Resume Next
Set objItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
On Error GoTo 0

If Not objItem Is Nothing Then
    ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso (strId)
Else
    ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso (strId)
End If

End Sub
```

With this you do not have access to the parameters as with Excel.